# Member detection based on custom void_t implementation

Tags: c++, templates, traits, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I've got the book C++ Templates the complete guide and I'm trying to implement some of the described techniques. One of these is member function detection, but my implementation seems not working.

I can't use void_t as I'm using C++11, but I copied the definition, so this should be not the problem.

Following is the code:

```
namespace nt_detail
  {
  template< class... >
  using void_t = void;
  }

template<typename T, typename = nt_detail::void_t<>>
struct HasHelloMember
    : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct HasHelloMember<T,
    nt_detail::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().hello())>>
       : std::true_type {};
```

and here the test one:

```
class ZZZ
  {

  };

class ZZZ2
  {
  public:
  void hello()
    {}
  };

int main()
  {
  if(HasHelloMember<ZZZ>::value)
    {
    std::cout << "ZZZ has hello" << std::endl;
    }
  else
    {
    std::cout << "ZZZ has NOT hello" << std::endl;
    }



if(HasHelloMember<ZZZ2>::value)
  {
  std::cout << "ZZZ2 has hello" << std::endl;
  }
else
  {
  std::cout << "ZZZ2 has NOT hello" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

In both cases I get "has hello". Is there something wrong with my void_t implementation perhaps?

Comment: What compier are you using? [Could not reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a92729ec4d81e307).

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.8.5

Comment: Is upgrading a possibility? gcc5.1 is what you'd need.

Comment: @YSC are you saying that it's just a compiler bug or a C++11 "problem"?

Comment: It's a C++11 non-guarantee which as been removed in C++14, but compilers fixed it before; at least gcc and clang.

Comment: Ok, I think however it's ok the @bartop solution because it works with C++11 too and I'd like to make my code portable even on other GCC versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this definition of `void_t` unless You are using C++17:

```
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
```

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t:

> Until CWG 1558 (a C++14 defect), unused parameters in alias templates
>   were not guaranteed to ensure SFINAE and could be ignored, so earlier
>   compilers require a more complex definition of void_t, such as

This is an issue with gcc until version 5.1.

Comment: @YSC As the text writes - it may work but it is not guaranteed

Comment: thank you! it was indeed the void_t definition, now it correctly works. PS had connection problems

Comment: Which makes it a nice answer. FYI this quirk [has been resolved in gcc5.1](https://godbolt.org/z/YL8HO0). @bartop you might add that in your answer.